How can I pass `-gdb tcp::1234` argument for qemu from the linux command line?
This question is related to How can I debug qemu code and the application on the qemu machine at the same time? . Though I can set the arguments for ddd inside ddd's command window, it would be convenient if I could give ddd the whole arguments from the linux command line.
The problem is, if launch ddd with ddd qemu-system-aarch64 command, and I give this command inside the ddd's command window, the qemu program understands it.
set args -machine ab21q,gic-version=max,secure=on,virtualization=true -cpu max -device loader,file=spl/u-boot-spl,addr=0x4000000 -m 1G -nographic -device loader,file=../../LinuxDevDrv/linux-5.15.68/arch/arm64/boot/Image,addr=0x80200000 -gdb tcp::1235 -S

But if I give this arg list in the linux command shell like this,
$ ddd --args ../../QEMU/qemu-6.2.0/build-baremetal/qemu-system-aarch64 -machine ab21q,gic-version=max,secure=on,virtualization=true -cpu max -device loader,file=spl/u-boot-spl,addr=0x4000000 -m 1G -nographic -device loader,file=../../LinuxDevDrv/linux-5.15.68/arch/arm64/boot/Image,addr=0x80200000 -gdb tcp::1235 -S

then, ddd gives me this error inside its command window.
qemu-system-aarch64: tcp::1235: Unknown protocol 'tcp'

Surely -gdb tcp::1235 is the argument for qemu and if I give it inside the ddd command window, ddd understands it, but if I pass it with other arguments with --args for the ddd, qemu doesn't understand it. It looks like the -gdb part is intercepted by ddd and only tcp::1235 is being passed to qemu. How can I get around this problem??

You can stop ddd from processing further arguments using '--'. If you try "ddd -- --args path/to/qemu args for qemu"  does that work ? (Technically --args is not handled by ddd, but by the "inferior debugger", which is to say gdb; and -- means "everything after this is for the inferior debugger, not for ddd".)

Hi, thanks. So when I tried "ddd -command=gdb_script_qemu  -geometry 1581x1818+4026+121 -- --args ${QEMU_DIR}/qemu-system-aarch64 -machine ${QMACHINE},gic-version=max,secure=${QSECURE},virtualization=true -cpu ${QCPU} -device loader,file=spl/u-boot-spl -m ${MEMSIZE} -nographic -device loader,file=${KERNEL_IMAGE},addr=${KERNEL_LOAD_ADDR} } -gdb tcp::1235 -S", and when I give run command in the gdb command window, it gives me "qemu-system-aarch64: -command=gdb_script_qemu: invalid option". Strange, even argument before -- was passed to qemu.

I think at this point this is problems with ddd itself, and nothing related to QEMU: it seems to behave rather oddly when it tries to set up the command line to invoke gdb. You might do best to try whatever support forums or channels are available for ddd.

@PeterMaydell Oh, because those after -- are for inferior debugger as you said, I moved all the args for ddd in front of -- like this. "ddd -geometry 1581x1818+4026+121 -- -command=gdb_script_qemu  --args ../../QEMU/qemu-6.2.0/build-baremetal/aarch64-softmmu/qemu-system-aarch64 -machine ab21q,gic-version=max,secure=on,virtualization=true -cpu max -device loader,file=spl/u-boot-spl -m 1G -nographic -device loader,file=../../LinuxDevDrv/linux-5.15.68/arch/arm64/boot/Image,addr=0x80200000 -gdb tcp::1235 -S", now at least it runs without comlaint. (though I need another gdb to attach to u-boot..)

@PeterMaydell Please put a short answer for this and I'll make it a selected answer so that others can easily see the answer.

You can stop ddd from processing further arguments using '--'; everything after that it will hand to what it calls the "inferior debugger", which is gdb. '--args' is a gdb option, and everything after that is the command to run and its arguments. So you want a command line like:
ddd [arguments for ddd] -- [arguments for gdb] --args [qemu binary] [arguments for qemu]

It's probably most reliable to keep a strict separation between gdb arguments and dd arguments; discussion in comments suggests that if ddd finds a gdb argument before '--' it doesn't put it in the right place on the gdb command line.

Thanks as always! Learned a good thing.
